# How to build a list of classes annotated with my custom annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to get a complete list of classes in the application which are annotated with `@Custom` annotation. What is the best mechanism for this operation?

ps. For example, how JAX-RS implementations find all classes that are annotated with `@Path`? I would like to use the same mechanism.

Comment: Do you want to search in source code (.java) or in compiled code (.class)?

Comment: No, I don't use any IDE. I'm interested only in compiled code in my JAR.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usually this is done using the process called classpath scanning. In general class loaders do not allow for scanning through all the classes on the classpath. But usually the only used class loader is `UrlClassLoader` from which we can retrieve the list of directories and jar files (see [getURLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#getURLs%28%29)) and open them one by one to list available classes.

This approach is implemented by libraries like [Scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/) and [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Another approach is to use [Java Pluggable Annotation Processing API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) to write annotation processor which will collect all annotated classes at compile time and build the index file for runtime use.

The above mechanism is implemented in [ClassIndex](https://github.com/atteo/classindex) library.

Using classpath scanning is usually two orders of magnitude slower than compile-time indexing. See [this benchmark](https://github.com/atteo/classindex#why-classindex).

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but I ran across it in my own search for classpath scanning and found another good answer, so I'm adding it here.

[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a [ClassPath](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#classpath) object that provides "best effort" classpath scanning (which is all any classpath scanning utility offers, really). Since Guava is a widely-adopted, carefully-maintained utility library, this is a great option for projects that either (a) are already using Guava, or (b) need a stable library they can rely on for classpath scanning.

Answer (score 4):

[classindex](https://github.com/atteo/classindex) is a compile-time annotation scanning library, implemented using an annotation processor.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find my solution with this library

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

You could try my library [FastClasspathScanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner):

```
List<String> classNames = new FastClassPathScanner("com.mypackage")
    .scan()
    .getNamesOfClassesWithAnnotation(Custom.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know by now, Java has no way to enumerate all packages or the classes in each package. So you have to do it the "hard" way. Options:

1. Use a tool like `grep` to search for the annotation. Advantage: Fast, simple. Drawbacks: Might return false positives (like classes where the annotation is commented out).
2. Compile the code and process the result with `javap`. That works on the bytecode level[*]. It gives you accurate results but the output of `javap` isn't really meant for automatic processing.
3. Use a bytecode library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). Not for the faint of heart but it allows you to access other data as well (like implemented interfaces, fields, etc) in relation to the annotation.
4. Last option: Eclipse uses its own Java compiler which can build an AST from Java code (even if the code doesn't compile). Advantage over ASM: You get a model for Java code for free. Makes certain operations more simple. No so easy to set up, though. [See my blog for an example](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/11/05/using-eclipse-to-parse-java-code/).

[*]: The annotation must have `Retention.RUNTIME` for this to work.

Comment: First Option = arggghh. All others: +1

Comment: Which of your options JAX-RS implementations are using, Jersey for example, to find all `@Path`-annotated classes?

Comment: Care to give evidence for your claim that there is no way? Especially in light of the library I linked to in my answer?

Comment: Jersey is using classpath scanning: [https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.3/jersey/com/sun/jersey/core/spi/scanning/JarFileScanner.html](JarFileScanner)

Comment: That's correct; note that the classpath at runtime can be different from the one at compile time. Therefore classpath scanning is brittle. Examining the system property `java.class.path` can lead to wrong results when your code runs in an application server or when you use custom classloaders. Not all classloaders allow to examine the paths where classes are loaded from. Therefore my claim: Java doesn't have an API to do this. You have to resort to some kind of hack.

Comment: I just want to point out that you can actually get that information at run-time BUT you need to use reflection to make the "classes" property public on the ClassLoader you are using. This is not recommended and can break in newer versions of Java (there is no guarantee that a private method will be there on the next version). More information in http://stolenkid.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/browse-classloader/

Comment: @Hoffmann: +1 I solved this in a similar way in a helper class but it's a bit tedious to figure out the "classes" property to read for all class loaders especially when I have to get this information from customers from the error log and even more so when the property changes between versions.

Comment: @AaronDigulla the bigger danger is you make your application work fine on say Java 6, then it keeps working fine in Java 7, but come Java 8 that private property name changed to "loadedClasses" and then your application no longer works and you have no idea why. I would avoid using it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Hoffmann: As I said, my code does check for the property and then prints additional information when it's missing/wrong type/etc. That way, I know why it breaks. But it's still a hack. Oracle should really provide an API to enumerate elements in a package.

Answer (score 0):

Run a find in your IDE on the source, If you trying to do this on compiled classes you would have add a method to them to support this, even if you decompiled the classes I do not think annotations or comments would show up.

Comment: @Brian yes, if the annotation's `@Retention` is `RUNTIME`

Comment: ... if they are defined with `@Retention(RUNTIME)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use an IDE [as Jesus suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107498/how-to-build-a-list-of-classes-annotated-with-my-custom-annotation/4107554#4107554).

But you could also

- write an [annotation processor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) that logs all occurrences of the annotation
- write an AspectJ aspect and [declare a warning for this annotation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-decp.html#declare-error-and-declare-warning) (I know, warning is probably not what you want, but there is no INFO in AspectJ)
- use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to check the byte code for the annotation
- use [a Source Parser](http://javaparser.googlecode.com/) to check the source code for the annotation

Beware: All of these are tricky. The AspectJ solution should be the simplest.