# How should I invoke class static initialization?

Tags: java, static, annotations, initialization

I have many GUI element types and use them directly in code after GUI loading. That would be OK unless GUI loader needs to know about existing elements to create them.

```
public final class VerticalBox extends Element {

    ...

    private static final ElementType type;
    static {
        type = ElementType.register("VerticalBox",
                new ElementType.ICreator() {
                    @Override
                    public Element create(GUI gui) {
                        return new VerticalBox(gui);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public ElementType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

The easiest method is to create static `init` function inside each element class, but them I will need to call `init` for each one.

I've seen some annotations in JavaEE, but they seem to be working opposite way. I can get all `annotations` from `class`, but not `classes` from `annotation`. I've did a lot of googling on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use some sort of dependency injection here, which will initialize things on demand. It's worth looking at Spring Framework, or Google Guice, or Pico Container.

In most cases it's bad idea to have static blocks, because you don't have full control over them, and it complicates unit testing a lot - order of tests does matter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107498/how-to-build-a-list-of-classes-annotated-with-my-custom-annotation) or, if you classes are split over several jars you want to keep independent, the [ServiceLoader mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html) might o the trick for you.