# How to get a collection of tests in a JUnit 4 test suite

Tags: java, junit, test-suite

In JUnit 3, I could get all of the tests within a test suite with the following code:

```
TestSuite allTestsSuite = (TestSuite) AllTests.suite()
Enumeration enumeration = allTestsSuite.tests();
ArrayList listOfTests = Collection.list(enumeration);
```

However, I can't find an equivalent way of doing this in JUnit 4. Classes no longer have a `.suite()` method; they simply use the `@Suite` annotation. This wouldn't be a problem except that the [Suite class](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html) no longer has a `tests()` method. There is a `children()` method, but that returns a list of Runners, which seem to be something different than why I'm looking for.

So how can I get the tests within a test suite in JUnit 4, like I could with JUnit 3?

Comment: Maybe you can [scan the annotated classess][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107498/how-to-build-a-list-of-classes-annotated-with-my-custom-annotation

Comment: Why would you want the tests?  There are different solutions for different use cases.  Different runners could also dynamically generate new tests so it might be difficult to get a full list of Junit 4 tests until you actually run them.

Comment: @Dkatzel I'm working on some legacy code that analyzes the makeup of a JUnit suite and checks that the right tests are in the right suite (e.g. make sure that someone didn't put a GUI test in the database suite). Perhaps it's unnecessarily pedantic, but unfortuantely I don't have any say in that right now, so I'm trying to find a JUnit 4 equivalent to the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I discovered the following solution:

```
SuiteClasses suiteClassesAnnotation = AllTests.class.getAnnotation(SuiteClasses.class);
if (suiteClassesAnnotation == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("This class isn't annotated with @SuiteClasses");
Class<?>[] classesInSuite = suiteClassesAnnotation.value();
```

Basically, it gets the classes the same way that JUnit itself gets them: by looking into the annotation and determining which values are included within it.

The category solution provided by dkatzel is also a good option if you're ultimately wanting to filter these classes, but if you need a list of classes in a suite for some other purpose such as code analysis, this is the simplest and most direct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to perform any kind of filering is to create your own JUnit `Categories`.

See this [Junit Category tutorial](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0) for more details but basically, you create your own categories named whatever you want

```
public interface GuiTest{ }

public interface DbTest {  }
```

And now you can annotate either entire test classes or individual tests with that category:

```
@Category(GuiTest.class)
public void myJPanelTest{


    @Test
    public void testFoo(){
        ...
    }

    //look we can have other categories too
    @Test
    @Category(DbTest.class)
    public void accidentalDbTest(){

    }
}
```

Then in your test suite, you can specify to include or exclude tests that match the given category

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(GuiTest.class)
@ExcludeCategory(DbTest.class)  //not sure if we need both but can't hurt
@SuiteClasses( {
     ...
 })
public class GuiTestsOnlySuite{}
```

Using Categories is much better than having to come up with manually filtering tests based on ad-hoc naming conventions because it that is hard to remember to do (and to make sure everyone in your group adheres to the naming conventions) and since the categories are classes, you can use your IDE to search/refactor/ compile time check your category names.

The only downside I've seen is at least in my IDE, the tests take a little longer to run because there is extra reflection work to do to make sure the test matches your category filter criteria before it runs.